# Renewing a whetstone?

Tags: equipment, sharpening, knife-safety

I think my whetstone has **smoothed over** by constant use at work, is there a way to repair it or should I just go buy another?

Comment: What kind of whetstone is this - oilstone, ceramic waterstone, soft synthetic waterstone, natural waterstone?

Comment: a photo would be helpful

Comment: I believe it is a natural whetstone, would a flattening stone help at all?

Comment: Picture, please?  Is it circular, cylindrical, cuboid? What material is it made of?

Comment: Do you wet the stone before use? Oil it occasionally?

Comment: I do the full soak in water till no air bubbles rise, also I'm away formwork so I can get a picture yet. It's a rectangular double grain two sided whetstone either all natural or half natural half ceramic.

Comment: A waterstone it is then ... most of them should rarely get clogged as badly as you describe... and yes, in most cases a flattening stone will be effective on these.

Answer (score 0):

Use a nagura flattening stone to remove as much material as required.

Comment: Anything flat and abrasive should work. I am using some flattened clinker bricks to flatten whetstones for sharpening woodworking tools, but a sheet of sandpaper on a piece of glass also works. Probably even a piece of concrete...